# How to find the absolute value of a complex function?

Tags: python

I want to find the absolute value of something like 'i' but when I type 'abs(1)' it says 'i' is not defined. What do I do?

Comment: *"when I type 'abs(1)' it says 'i' is not defined"* <- that seems unlikely. Do you mean when you type `abs(i)`? Because that's not a valid complex literal in Python, see e.g. https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#imaginary-literals, it's just trying to refer to the name `i`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In python to find the absolute value of a complex function you use j instead of i.

```
abs(a+bj) # General Format
abs(0+1j)
>> 1
```

Or you could define i as the square root of -1 and use it instead

```
i = (-1) ** 0.5
abs(i)
>> 1
```

Comment: @BennnHBennnH also FYI https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: @imaad, your second example should be `(-1)**0.5`, right now you're doing `-(1**0.5)` as can be seen checking the value of `i` itself rather than `abs(i)`, (it gives `-1` rather than `1j`)